# Handling large amount of an event handlers

Tags: c#, events, windows-store-apps

I have a control which can raise events.

```
public event EventHandler ValueUpdated;
```

I subscribe to this event

```
classInstance.ValueUpdated += handler;

...

public void handler(...)
{
  oneObject.DoSmthg(...)
}
```

Now the problem is that this event can be raised 1 time in 1 min or 1000 times in a second. Which leads to poor performances (`oneObject.DoSmthg(...)` isn't a long-task run but isn't neutral in term of performances).

I don't care of intermediate steps. For example, if the event is raised 1000 times in a second, just execute the `handler` method for the first event rising and the last one is perfectly ok since this is for display purposes.

What is the best approach to execute a sort of "if many call stacked execute only the last one" ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy situation to handle using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main").

So given this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler ValueUpdated;
}
```

I can write this code to turn the event into an Rx Observable that only fires at most once a second:

```
var values =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern(h => foo.ValueUpdated += h, h => foo.ValueUpdated -= h)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

Throttle has this semantic:

> Ignores the values from an observable sequence which are followed by another value before due time with the specified source and dueTime.

Now I can subscribe (attach) to the observable like so:

```
var subscription =
    values
        .Subscribe(ep =>
        {
            /* handle event here */
        });
```

To unsubscribe (detach) from the observable by calling:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is a control, you probably only want to perform the operation after the user has finished interacting with the control. As such, in your `PropertyChanged` event handler, stop and kick off a `DispatcherTimer` which when it triggers will kick off the long running process. The reason to stop and then kick off the timer again is because it effectively restarts the timer.

An implementation of this might look as follows (assume long running process is kicked off by `ExternalEvent`):

```
public event ChangedEvent ExternalEvent;

private DispatcherTimer _timer;

private ChangedEventArgs _lastChangedArgs;

public MyControl()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,350);
    InternalEventGeneratingControl.ChangedEvent += new ChangedEventHandler(ChangedHandler);
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
   if (ExternalEvent != null)
       ExternalEvent(this, _lastChangedArgs);
}

private void ChangedHandler(object sender, ChangedEventArgs e)
{
   _timer.Stop();
   _lastChangedArgs = e;
   _timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `handler`, start or reset a timer with your desired timeout `N`. When the timeout gets triggered, no events were received for `N` time, so you can start processing.

Stop the timer before starting to process.

Comment: Good point. But this is not very sexy solution, since two computers can have a very different compute time. In addition to that, this don't ensure that the LAST one is executed :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your first remark, and I don't think your second one is true. You could also just store the events and their receive date in a list, and let another thread process that list. The term you're looking for is to "de-bounce an event" anyway.

Comment: Yay ! Thx for the key word, exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth to have a look to Reactive Extensions I think:

http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)